# Parsing xml based on a value

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi my xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><people>
<person>
    <key>title</key>
    <details>Kate</details>
    <contact>Smith</contact>
    <age>27</age>
    <key>childnodes</key>
 <person>
     <key>All</key>
     <details>Details</details>
     <contact>900033</contact>
      <details>Adress</details>
      <contact>housenumber</contact>
  </person>
</person>
<person>
    <key>title</key>
    <contact>Manu</contact>
    <age>30</age>
    <key>childnodes</key>
 <person>
     <key>subnode</key>
     <details>Details</details>
     <contact>Premraj</contact>
      <details>Gandhinagar</details>
      <contact>888444</contact>
  </person>
</person>
<person>
    <details>Ann</details>
    <contact>Peterson</contact>
    <age>27</age>
</person>
</people>
```

I want to parse the xml in two ways that is if the key  contains "childnodes" that is     ('< key>childnodes< key >') then add the datas to list box or a list and if no "childnodes" adding the values to listbox1 or list1.The thing is that i have to check the node key for if it contains children.If you knows the solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you have an invalid XML. You are missing a `</contact>` closing tag, as well as `</people>`. Also, the structure is horrible considering how you are handling chid entries. It should be like this instead:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>title</name>
    <address>Kate</address>
    <phone>Smith</phone>
    <age>27</age>
    <children>
      <person>
        <name>sub</name>
        <address>Details</address>
        <phone>900033</phone>
      </person>
    </children>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>title</name>
    <phone>Manu</phone>
    <age>30</age>
    <children>
      <person>
        <name>AnotherName</name>
        <address>Details</address>
        <phone>900033</phone>
      </person>
    </children>
  </person>
</people>
```

Second, you could serialize your class and then perform the appropriate bindings. For example, a general serialization structure for your case would look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("people")]
public class People
{
    [XmlElement("person")]
    public List<Person> RegisteredPeople { get; set; } 
}

public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("children")]
    [XmlArrayItem("person")]
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The deserializer should act like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
StringReader reader = new StringReader(YOUR_XML);
People p = (People)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```